# Issue in adding dropdown list for feets and inches and calculation?

Tags: javascript, html

I had created a code for BMR calculator and it is working without adding the dropdown but when I add a dropdown list for feet and inches and other tables like kg,cm blocks click on the caluclate button it is not working.

Please any one help me.

My code :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type"  content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="easyui.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script><script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easyui.min.js"></script><style   type="text/css">
 .panel-body {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   color: #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
   }
  .tabs-title {
   font-size: 15px;
  }
   </style>

 <div class="easyui-tabs" style="width:450px;height:250px">
   <div id="rechner" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px #444444; padding:15px; margin:10px; width:310px; border-radius:15px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,'sans-serif'; font-size: 11px;">
<p style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;text-align:center;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Calculate your BMR in US metrics</p>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Gender:</td><td>

        <input type="radio" name="sex1" value="male" checked>Male<input type="radio" name="sex1" value="female">Female</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Age:</td><td>
        <input type="text" size="5" name="age1" id="age1" value="0" onBlur=checkPositiveInteger(this) onChange=checkPositiveInteger(this)></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Height:</td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="height1" id="height1" value="0" onBlur=checkNotNegative(this) onChange=checkNotNegative(this)> feet <input type="text" size="5" id="height2" value="0"  onBlur=checkNotNegative(this) onChange=checkNotNegative(this)> inches</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Weight:</td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="weight1" id="weight1" value="0" onBlur=checkPositive(this) onChange=checkPositive(this)> pounds</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton"  onclick="calculate1()"><button type="button">Calculate</button></a></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Your BMR:</td><td><input type="text" size="10" id="bmr1"> calories/day</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="rechner" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px #444444; padding:15px; margin:10px;width:310px;border-radius:15px; font-family:Verdana,Arial,'sans-serif';font-size:11px;background: url(http://www.bmi-rechner.net/images/box_bg.png);">
    <p style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;text-align:center;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Calculate your BMR in EU metrics</p>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Gender:</td><td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Age:</td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="age" id="age" value="0" onBlur=checkPositiveInteger(this) onChange=checkPositiveInteger(this)></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Height:</td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="height" id="height" value="0" onBlur=checkPositive(this) onChange=checkPositive(this)> centimeters</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Weight:</td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="weight" id="weight" value="0" onBlur=checkPositive(this) onChange=checkPositive(this)> kilograms</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="calculate()"><button type="button">Calculate</button></a></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Your BMR:</td><td><input type="text" size="10" id="bmr"> calories/day</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
  </div>
  <script>

 function calculate(){

 var age=document.getElementById("age").value;
var height=document.getElementById("height").value;
var weight=document.getElementById("weight").value;

var sex;
var x=document.getElementsByName("sex");
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if(x[i].checked==true){
        sex=x[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
var bmr;
if(sex=="female"){
    //bmr=655+(9.6*weight)+(1.7*height)-(4.7*age);
    bmr=10*weight+6.25*height-5*age-161;
    document.getElementById("bmr").value=round(bmr);
}else if(sex=="male"){
    //bmr=66+(13.7*weight)+(5.0*height)-(6.8*age);
    bmr=10*weight+6.25*height-5*age+5;
    document.getElementById("bmr").value=round(bmr);
}else{
    alert("You must select a sex.");
}
}
 function checkPositive(field){
var number=field.value;
if(isNaN(number)||number.length==0){
    alert("This field must be a number.");
    field.focus();
}else if(number<=0){
    alert("This number must be positive.");
    field.focus();
}else{
 }
 }
function checkPositiveInteger(field){
var number=field.value;
var number1=Math.floor(number);
if(isNaN(number)||number.length==0){
    alert("This field must be a number.");
    field.focus();
}else if(number<=0){
    alert("This number must be positive.");
    field.focus();
}else if(number-number1!=0){
    alert("This number must be a Integer.");
    field.focus();
}else{
}
}
function checkNotNegative(field){
var number=field.value;
if(isNaN(number)||number.length==0){
    alert("This field must be a number.");
    field.focus();
}else if(number<0){
    alert("This number must be positive or 0.");
    field.focus();
}else{
 }
 }
 function calculate1(){
var age=document.getElementById("age1").value;
var feet=document.getElementById("height1").value;
var inches=document.getElementById("height2").value;
var weight=document.getElementById("weight1").value;
weight=weight*0.4535924;
var height=30.48*feet+inches*2.54;
var sex;
var x=document.getElementsByName("sex1");
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if(x[i].checked==true){
        sex=x[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
var bmr;
if(sex=="female"){
    //bmr=655+(9.6*weight)+(1.7*height)-(4.7*age);
    bmr=10*weight+6.25*height-5*age-161;
    document.getElementById("bmr1").value=round(bmr);
}else if(sex=="male"){
    //bmr=66+(13.7*weight)+(5.0*height)-(6.8*age);
    bmr=10*weight+6.25*height-5*age+5;
    document.getElementById("bmr1").value=round(bmr);
  }else{
    alert("You must select a sex.");
  }
     }
   function round(x){
return Math.round(x*1000)/1000;
     }
      </script></div></body></html>
```

I need to get the dropdown like below image

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I get what you are looking for, this Plunker is working pretty well for me http://plnkr.co/edit/XVOmR6OqI3BG96MsC6ht

Comment: I attached the image.please check it I need in that way.

Comment: it's difficult to help you because you have fiddle an example that working, is better if you post what's not working. But have you see if you have put the same names at the different fields of "height" and "weight"? post the fiddle with the error

Comment: As in fiddle I am getting.Please check the attached image in that for height it has a up and down keys in that way i tried but it is not working.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok try this:

```
<tr><td>Height:</td><td><input type="number" size="5" name="height" id="height" value="0" onBlur=checkPositive(this) onChange=checkPositive(this)> centimeters</td></tr>
<tr><td>Weight:</td><td><input type="number" size="5" name="weight" id="weight" value="0" onBlur=checkPositive(this) onChange=checkPositive(this)> kilograms</td></tr>
```

to me this is working in the fiddle.

If there are some problems more, i can save the mods in the fiddle.

UPDATE

I've forked the mod in the fiddle.

 UPDATE

i don't know why but i can't save the fiddle anymore so i write here what you have to do at all you if else case

```
if(number!=""||isNaN(number)||number.length==0){
    alert("This field must be a number.");
    field.focus();
}else if(number<=0){
    alert("This number must be positive.");
    field.focus();
}else{
```

you have to count the number!="". 

UPDATE

to cancel the onchange or the onblur function you can use the on click on the button "calculate" and call the same function into that, passing to it the same variable.

 UPDATE

```
function checkPositive(field){
    if (field.value=="")
        return;
```

write this in all you're methods.

 I have try to fork again the fiddle, try if it has take the mods.http://plnkr.co/edit/YS1KQ5BIILXhHdcaVE6G?p=preview

UPDATE

http://plnkr.co/edit/cVK9V88YafVgD4jbqwHd?p=preview

that's the fiddle with the negative number prevented, but i think that this question is now completely answered:)

UPDATE
http://plnkr.co/edit/L4w29rrFMMtCmWaQWKTw?p=preview

 this must be work to not make the number not go under 0.

Comment: Have you checked the code it already present in the code.If you see the image you can get the correct idea what I am asking.I hope you understand my issue as in the image I need.

Comment: looking at you're code and at you're fiddle you have write "input type="text" " but you need number, or i'm wrong?

Comment: Ok.If I delete the value="25" in the code it is showing alert and I deleted the onchange code after deleting it is not working.Can you please help me]

Comment: fork the fiddle so i can see it:)

Comment: I don't want to add onchange in script and html code.You can see my code here:http://plnkr.co/edit/uWBLVdexYAont9Utw5i6?p=preview

Comment: the error is in your if... else case, you have to provide a case for an empty string, i have fork a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87966/discussion-between-mautrok-and-mouni).

Comment: where is your fiddle?I could not see.Please provide of your changes

Comment: I don't want those functions.I need to delete the checkPostive() and other functions like those.The code is so big without that "onblur" and "onchange" can't we run the code.

Comment: I don't want to see those alerts and when I open the BMR calculation page the text fields should be empty.

Comment: Ok.But,It does not show the negative values and alerts in cm,feet and inches without showing the alert it has to start the value at 10.

Comment: the philosophy are the same... it's called the "limit cases" you have to put a "return" immediatly at the begin of the methods when the values passed (in this case field.value) is not what you're expecting.

Comment: No.It doesn't show any alert when I select before 0 it should not go to the negative value.It has to starts with 10 when I press the down key for Age and other for feets it should not go for negative values.the down key should not work if the number is less than '0'.I hope you understand my requirement.:-)